# Setting JButtons at specific location on JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

I have a jpanel with some animation on it, I want to add two or more buttons, for example start\pause, ffw and etc.
I tried to use JButton.setBorders(), and also changing the layout. But the button either appear on top screen or overlap each other when I am using setLayout(). How can I put those two buttons at the bottom of the screen at each side (left and right).
Here is my code:

```
public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Cell[][] cellMatrix;
private Options op;
private Dimension expectedDimension;

private JPanel startButtonPanel;
private JPanel pauseButtonPanel;

private JButton startButton;
private JButton pauseButton;

Animation(Options received) {

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    startButtonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    startButtonPanel.add(startButton);
    this.add(startButtonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
    pauseButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    pauseButtonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    pauseButtonPanel.add(pauseButton);
    this.add(pauseButtonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    this.op = received;

    expectedDimension = new Dimension((op.getNumberOfCells()*10) , (op.getNumberOfCells()*10));
    setPreferredSize(expectedDimension);
    setMaximumSize(expectedDimension);
    setMinimumSize(expectedDimension);


    this.cellMatrix = new Cell[op.getNumberOfCells()][op.getNumberOfCells()];
}
```

Here is a screenshot
[image: As you can see the pause button has a huge size and also overlaps the start button]

Comment: A `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout` to space the buttons, placed in the `SOUTH` position of the parent container using a `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You may want the south panel to use a `BoxLayout` on the X axis.

A horizontal glue between buttons, will ensure that each one stays on its side of the panel :

```
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
buttonsPanel.add(pauseButton);

// create a glue between buttons
buttonsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());


JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
buttonsPanel.add(startButton);

this.add(buttonsPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to also add another button in between them?

Comment: @Keselme : yes of course, you can add other components and other glues as you need, like comp-glue-comp-glue-...